# How to convert a csv file to lowercase/uppercase maintaining its structure?

Tags: r, csv, tolower

I have a csv file with some columns, each column has values written in different ways, such as  "Car" and "CAR". I wish to convert all values to lowercase, I'm using this code:

```
data <- read.table(pipe("cut -d' ' -f6 iis_raw.csv"))
data <- tolower(data)
```

But the result is a bunch of values like:

```
70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 61, 61, 61, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 70, 70, 70)"
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to apply `tolower` on a `data.frame` directly. You should use `lapply` instead:

```
X <- read.table(text = "V1,V2,V3
                A,B,C
                A,B,D
                A,G,X
                a,g,f", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
X
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  A  B  C
# 2  A  B  D
# 3  A  G  X
# 4  a  g  f
tolower(X)
# [1] "c(2, 2, 2, 1)" "c(1, 1, 3, 2)" "c(1, 2, 4, 3)"
lapply(X, tolower)
# $V1
# [1] "a" "a" "a" "a"
# 
# $V2
# [1] "b" "b" "g" "g"
# 
# $V3
# [1] "c" "d" "x" "f"

X[] <- lapply(X, tolower)
X
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  a  b  c
# 2  a  b  d
# 3  a  g  x
# 4  a  g  f
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
data[] <- lapply(data, tolower)
```

As I don't think you can use `tolower` ona dataframe like this.  Here I do this witht he `CO2` data set.

```
CO2[] <- lapply(CO2, tolower)
```

Comment: Did we really post our answers  virtually the same time? +1 for the train of thought.